# Obtain IP address of connecting client in Clisp

Tags: sockets, networking, ip-address, common-lisp, clisp

So I have a server, written in Common Lisp to be run in the Clisp interpreter. When a client connects to the aforementioned server, I need a way to obtain their IP address. Is a function that would allow me to do this? Google-Fu is yielding limited results. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOCKET:SOCKET-STREAM-PEER](http://clisp.org/impnotes/socket.html#sost-peer) will do what you want.